# Java JLabel.getLocation() always returning 0

Tags: location, jlabel

I'm studying Java so I'm pretty new.
I'm creating a simple 'maze' type game using GUI layouts, images, labels ect..

To create my maze layouts I used an array of strings;

```
    mazeLayout[0] = "WWWWWWWWWW";
    mazeLayout[1] = "WSSSWWSWWW";
    mazeLayout[2] = "WSWSWWSSSW";
    mazeLayout[3] = "WSWSWWWWSW";
    mazeLayout[4] = "WSWSWWWWSW";
    mazeLayout[5] = "WSWSWSSSSW";
    mazeLayout[6] = "WSWSWSWWWW";
    mazeLayout[7] = "WSWSWSWWWW";
    mazeLayout[8] = "WSWSSSWWWW";
    mazeLayout[9] = "WWWWWWWWWW";
```

and then converted this into a 2d array and placed a label with in image icon in it depending on the string being 'W' for wall or 'S' for space. Also the labels are an array, my thoughts behind this was for restricting movement of the player so they can't walk though walls.

```
int mw = 0;
int mf = 0;
for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        mazeLayout2d[y][x] = mazeLayout[y].substring(x, x+1);
        if (mazeLayout2d[y][x].equals("W")){
            lblmazewall[mw] = new JLabel();
            mazewall = new ImageIcon("mazewall.png");
            lblmazewall[mw].setIcon(mazewall);
            pCenter.add(lblmazewall[mw]);
            mw++;
            pCenter.revalidate();

        }
        if (mazeLayout2d[y][x].equals("S")){
            lblmazefloor[mf] = new JLabel();
            mazefloor = new ImageIcon("mazefloor.png");
            lblmazefloor[mf].setIcon(mazefloor);
            pCenter.add(lblmazefloor[mf]);
            mf++;
            pCenter.revalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when i run this line

```
System.out.println(lblmazewall[x].getLocation()); //x being any number
```

I always get java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]

I would like to know how to get the location of each wall label so i can check it against my player movement.

Is this even a valid way to do something like this?
Could someone teach me a more efficient way?

Sorry for my crude snippets and or bad programming

Thankyou Niall.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Point getLocation()
```

Due to the asynchronous nature of native event handling, this method can return outdated values (for instance, after several calls of `setLocation()` in rapid succession). For this reason, the recommended method of obtaining a component's position is within `java.awt.event.ComponentListener.componentMoved()`, which is called after the operating system has finished moving the component.

The layout might not have used `setLocation()` internally. So that getLocation() does not return the value as expected.